# Css infinite loop animation bug

Tags: css, animation

I see an annoying bug happening at the end of the animation loop, where it blinks for a fraction of a second, and makes the animation look choppy.

Here is the [pen](http://codepen.io/FlorinPop17/pen/PbzoWe).

SCSS:

```
$dim: 60px;
$mult: 1.8;
$color: #bada55;

body, html {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #36a;
}
.circle {
    background-color: $color;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: $dim;
    height: $dim;
    position: relative;
}

.circle:before {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    background-color: $color;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    animation: notification 800ms ease-in infinite;
}

@keyframes notification{
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        width: $dim;
        height: $dim;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }

    90% {
        opacity: 0;
        left: -(($dim * $mult) - $dim)/2;
        top: -(($dim * $mult) - $dim)/2;
        width: $dim * $mult;
        height: $dim * $mult;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        width: $dim;
        height: $dim;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
}
```

I've tried adding another frame, but it doesn't really remove it. I also tried hiding the before div afterwards, but doesn't work. Neither with z-index.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks even buggier in Chrome for me :-( it's even choppier.

Comment: It's opacity 0 already.

Comment: I don't really see what you mean. also ease-in isn't magic, it doesn't make everything smooth whatever you do.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the "choppy" behaviour is: You change the dimensions and the positioning of your element. This forces the browser to re-render the element (in this case your `:before` pseudo-element. This makes the calculation for the browser way harder than it has to be.

Instead of alternating the dimensions, you could use a simple `transform`. Transforming elements does not force a re-rendering of the element and therefore performs way smoother. Also, it makes the code a bit easier as well. I forked your CodePen and used the `transform` instead of the dimensions: http://codepen.io/HerrBertling/pen/NbrPJb

It's certainly not perfect concerning the animation and the dimensions, but it should run way smoother.

(Check e.g. this Medium post for further info about the browser's behaviour: https://medium.com/outsystems-experts/how-to-achieve-60-fps-animations-with-css3-db7b98610108#.sykm5uqyv)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but still it has the choppy ending... When it fades out, it appears again like it goes to opacity 1.

Comment: You might want to finetune the timeline of your animation then. Chrome Developer Tools are awesome for that – check this how-to: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/animations